# Extract some informations from html code

Tags: php, strip-tags

I would like to extract informations from an html code. Here is a part of it:

```
<li class="letter">#</li>
<li><a href="/fr/707/mot1/1.html" title="mot2">mot2</a><span>1234</span></li>      
<li><a href="/fr/1042/mot3/1.html" title="mot4">mot4</a><span>4567</span></li>
<li><a href="/fr/5697/mot5/1.html" title="mot6">mot6</a><span>3254</span></li>etc...
```

To get this result:

```
mot1,mot2
mot3,mot4
mot5,mot6
etc...
```

I tried with strip_tags but this doesn't get me far...

Thanks for your help.

Comment: use html parsing https://davidwalsh.name/php-notifications

Comment: You should be able to use [DOMdocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to handle this - without seeing your HTML it's hard to be more specific.

Comment: Sorry, but I had to. Low-effort question, low-effort answer: http://pastie.org/10906079 ;)

Comment: You should try showing the code you have. Please see here http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a blend of `preg_split`, `preg_match`, `array` and `foreach` Loop to get what you desire. In this case; you may just bundle all the **mot words** to an `array` like so:

```
<?php    
    $strMots    = '<li class="letter">#</li>
    <li><a href="/fr/707/mot/1.html" title="mot2">mot2</a><span>1234</span></li>
    <li><a href="/fr/707/mot1/1.html" title="mot2">mot2</a><span>1234</span></li>
    <li><a href="/fr/1042/mot3/1.html" title="mot4">mot4</a><span>4567</span></li>
    <li><a href="/fr/5697/mot5/1.html" title="mot6">mot6</a><span>3254</span></li>';

    // SPLIT THE STRING $strMots AT THE BOUNDARY "</li>"
    $arrSplits  = preg_split("#<\/li>#", $strMots);

    // CREATE AN ARRAY TO HOLD YOUR mot STRINGS
    $arrMots    = array();

    // USING FOREACH LOOP; ITERATE THROUGH ALL THE $arrSplits
    // WHILE YOU ARE AT IT, JUST CHECK IF EACH RECORD IN THE LOOP MATCHES 
    // A PATTERN THAT HAS THE WORD mot IN IT AND IF IT DOES,
    // PUSH IT TO AN ARRAY...
    foreach($arrSplits as $split){
        if(preg_match_all("#mot[0-9]+#si", $split, $matches)){
            if(!empty($matches)){
                foreach($matches as $match){
                    if(is_array($match)){
                        foreach($match as $motVal){
                            if(!in_array($motVal, $arrMots)){
                                $arrMots[]  = $motVal;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    var_dump($arrMots);

    // DISPLAYS:
    array (size=4)
      0 => string 'mot2' (length=4)
      1 => string 'mot1' (length=4)
      2 => string 'mot3' (length=4)
      3 => string 'mot4' (length=4)
      4 => string 'mot5' (length=4)
      5 => string 'mot6' (length=4)
```

**NOTE:** Please be informed that (as confirmable from the `var_dump()` above, the `Regular Expression` used here would not match just *mot* alone. That is: ***without a number-suffix*** like *mot9*.

Test it out [HERE](https://eval.in/604774).

Hope this gives you some ideas on how to improvise on your own.

Good Luck & Cheers ;-)